# SOLR Facet Response expanding with relation to synonym

Tags: solr

I have a strange issue where synonyms are getting expanded to the facet response. Please go over below data.

**Document**

```
[{
"size": "1"
},
"size": "23"
]
```

**Synonyms**

```
1,1ft,1feet
```

**SOLR Query**

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/techproducts/select?q=*:*&facet=true&facet.field=size&rows=0
```

**Response**

```
"facet_counts":{
    "facet_queries":{},
    "facet_fields":{
      "size":[
        "23",1112,
        "1",123,
        "1ft",123,
        "1feet",123]},
    "facet_ranges":{},
    "facet_intervals":{},
    "facet_heatmaps":{}}
}
```

Comment: What do you expect the result to be? If you expand synonyms when indexing, new tokens with those values are added to the index. If you don't want tokens to be created, expand synonyms when querying - or if you want to use index time synonyms, create a separate field where the synonyms are expanded, and then search against that field - and use the other field for faceting (without synonyms). You can use a `copyField` instruction to get the same content indexed into both fields.

Comment: It sounds strange to me to show expanded tokens in response. When I query the document never has this side effect, we don't show 2 different document one with size: 1 and another one with size: 1ft. Thanks for the work around, that should work.

Comment: But that's different. What gets returned for your query is the _stored value_ for the field, not its tokens. Tokens are the processed values that are used for searching, and faceting works with _the tokens_. So if you have `1` and `1ft` in your index to give hits for both `1` and `1ft`, both will be including when _faceting_.